# How to restrict textarea height and disable rows expanding

Tags: html, css, scroll, textarea

I'm trying to fix a textarea height and disable ability to expand rows while typing. So please note that I'm not just trying to "hide" scrollbar, or to prevent user from being able to resize text area using mouse.

Comment: What is your goal? If you want to limit the amount of rows/charactres one can enter set the `rows` and `maxlength` attributes of the textarea accordingly. If you want to avoid that line breaks are entered, filter them out.

Comment: When I set rows to let's say 10 and keep pressing "enter" the text area is still getting expanded and new rows are getting added... I want to prevent that behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a div and apply "contenteditable" = true.

Relevant changes required are:

This contents of this column should always be visible i.e. no scroll bar, and instead the height of this row should adjust to show all content.

Possible solution to fix the problem with textarea would be to use javascript.